# What's most efficient; creating a new instance or changing a value in an existing one?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write an application that keeps track of movies, as a way to get better at Java. For this I use a class "Movie" for the movies themselves, and classes such as "Title", "Year", "Director", etc. for what you might expect, that are all set through the "Movie" constructor. Now say I want to change the director of a movie, what would be the most efficient way of doing so from the "Movie" class? I boiled it down to either creating a new instance, or changing the old, i.e.

```
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = new Year(year);
}
```

or

```
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year.setYear(year);
}
```

Most of all, I'm just not sure if the second one is proper coding practice?

I just recently started learning Java, so I apologize for any confusion in my question.

Comment: You're asking if creating a new object (allocating memory, setting N variables, etc) is more efficient than changing a single value in an existing object ...

Comment: You won't notice a difference unless it's in large quantities. When you have those large quantities, obviously creating a new object is more expensive than changing a single field in the existing one but this would still be a fairly small difference. It's usually not important enough (and definitely not something trivial as a year) to worry about; it depends on your - subjective - design choices.

Comment: At an high level point of view this problem is irrelevant. And at an high level point of view I would prefer the first one which actually is not more efficient but give you an advantage, the Year class would be immutable

Comment: I guess I was just over thinking the whole thing. But it just felt weird to make a call from the main method to an instance, which would then just make another call to the next instance in question. Thanks, I'll run with what I had originally (the setter).

Comment: Most trivial code optimizations (ie. moving functions inline, unrolling loops) are performed when compiling, or by the VM running the bytecode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most performance questions, the best answer is;  worry about simple, clear coding first and it usually will performance well enough.  Only worry about performance issues if you have measured that you have a concern otherwise you are just guessing (even if you have ten years experience tuning Java applications)

The first example is the simplest and possibly the clearest, though I am not sure why you have a `Year` class at all given you are happy to pass in an `int` for a year.  The second is faster but more open to errors potentially.

If you just want the most efficient, use an `int`.

Best practice might be to use `Year` as an immutable everywhere e.g.

```
public void setYear(Year year) {
    this.year = year;
}
```

For example JodaTime has a variety of immutable classes to represent different time periods.

Comment: "worry about simple, clear coding first". YES. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/micro-optimization-and-meatballs.html

Comment: I removed all the code that doesn't relate to the question, but I have a "Year" class to check certain conditions and run further code when I feed it a value. Thanks for the answer, I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: It is much better to worry about program design and `O(n)` vs `O(log n)` than code level micro-optimizations.  Arguments about using encapsulation, or creating new objects vs reusing them, typically boil down to comparing `O(1)` to its self.

Comment: There is code where it really matters how many objects you create but it is less than 1% of code e.g. high frequency trading.  Correctness and clarity should always come first and tuning for performance can happen later if it is needed at all.

Answer (score 3):

In the words of Don Knuth, *"...premature optimization is the root of all evil"*

Based on your example, the first is the clearest. I would go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of both:

The typical way to go is

```
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}
```

You usually would not need a class Year.

However you should consider the audience of the class: Do you need to check for valid year,
or do you trust the caller.

From memory and speed performance the direct setting is more efficient, although you most probably would never feel a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Allocating an object is always expensive.  However, assigning a value to an object (copying) can also be expensive, but usually less so.  If you expect your code to be called often and performance is an issue, then consider copying.  Otherwise, do whatever is the easiest to read and write.